# Consultation regard to my android layout with adding list to my layout

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-studio

i have this layout
[type of a form to fill](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFl3S.jpg)

and inside there is an add button with little icon of plus on the left side,
when the user press this button he goes to another layout fill it and go back to this layout , and i want to add what ever he fill under this button , like a list 
, i have draw inside the picture an example of what i want to do ,
and if the user will add a lot of object to the list i need the layout to be scroll down,

**the form:**

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
android:columnCount="3"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:rowCount="10">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_columnSpan="3"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
    android:text="@string/xxxxx_position"
    android:textColor="@color/graydark"
    android:textSize="22dp" />

<!-- icon 1 -->
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="16dp"
    android:layout_height="16dp"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_bag_black_24dp" />

<!--end icon 1 -->
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-13dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_row="1">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/xx_profession"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:hint="Profession"
        android:textSize="13dp" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
<!-- icon 2 -->
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="16dp"
    android:layout_height="16dp"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_row="2"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_date_range_black_24dp" />

<!--end icon 2 -->
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-13dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_row="2">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/xx_experience"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:hint="Experience"
        android:textSize="13dp" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_columnSpan="2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_row="3"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
    android:text="Description"
    android:textColor="@color/red"
    android:textSize="12dp" />
<!-- row 3  -->
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="16dp"
    android:layout_height="16dp"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_margin="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_row="4"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_description_black_24dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/xx_description"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_columnSpan="2"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-13dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
    android:layout_row="4"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:lines="2"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:minLines="1" />


<!-- icon location -->
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="16dp"
    android:layout_height="16dp"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_row="5"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_place_black_24dp" />

<!--edittext location -->
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-13dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_row="5">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/xx_location"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="5"
        android:hint="Location"
        android:textSize="13dp" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="16dp"
    android:layout_height="16dp"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_margin="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:layout_row="6"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_school_black_24dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/xx"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_columnSpan="2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-15dp"
    android:layout_row="6"
    android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/add_xx_field"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:layout_row="6"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_add_circle_orange_24dp" />


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_columnSpan="3"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:layout_row="9"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_btn_xx"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/orange_button"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="25dp"
        android:paddingRight="25dp"
        android:text="ADD"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:translationX="-4dp"
        android:translationY="-5dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**what i want to do :**
form and under it a list of objects and when ever the user try to scroll this gridlayout the all page is scrolled

**the problem**:
if i set the objects inside listview within 10 row (on the gridlayout) i get scroll only on the listview and not scrolling the all gridlayout
i want something like a RecyclerView  , i can do it if i will create object and push it as a child inside linearlayout and warp this gridlayout with scrollview
but then if the user will add 100 object i will have memory problem
**need Consult**

Comment: grid/list/recycler view doesnt work with Scrollview

Comment: You can take linear layout & add view dynamically in it instead of taking listview inside grid

Comment: You can use `NestedScrollView`

Comment: user3040153 if i take linear layout i will have memory problem

Comment: i have tried NestedScrollView  but it not cancel listview scroller